# Register open generics with precedence

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, open-generics

Is it possible to use unity like so:

```
container.Register(typeof(IMyType<car>), typeof(MyType1<car>));
container.Register(typeof(IMyType<>), typeof(MyType2<>));
```

.. so that when I try to resolve `IMyType<car>` I get a `MyType1<car>`... but when I try to resolve `IMyType<bus>` I get `MyType2<bus>` ? Or perhaps another way to do the same thing so that a defined generic takes precedence over an open generic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly that:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType(typeof(IMyType<Car>), typeof(MyType1<Car>));
container.RegisterType(typeof(IMyType<>), typeof(MyType2<>));

// Returns MyType1<Car>:
IMyType<Car> car = container.Resolve<IMyType<Car>>();

// Returns MyType2<Bus>:
IMyType<Bus> bus = container.Resolve<IMyType<Bus>>();
```